# View single item inside kendo ui jquery scrollview

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a scrollview which get json data from an api and render items inside scrollview. From the data i only need to render one item at a time.

Inorder to do that i try adding pageSize:1 to the data source but it does not render anything inside the scrollview. When pageSize change to 2, items render fine with 2 items inside scrollview. 
How can i render only a one item inside scrollview?

```
<div id="example" style="margin:auto; width:60%">
    <div id="scrollView" style="height: 600px; width:100%;"></div>
</div>

<script id="scrollview-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    # for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { #
    <div  data-role="page" style="width:100%;">
        <img class="carousal-image" src="#= 
        getPreviewImageUrl(data[i].Type,data[i].PreviewImageUrl) #"/>
    </div>
    # } #
</script>

<script>
       var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "sample api",
                    dataType: "json"
                }
            },
            pageSize:1,
            schema: {
                data: "items"
            },

        });

        $("#scrollView").kendoScrollView({
            dataSource: dataSource,
            template: $("#scrollview-template").html(),
            contentHeight: "100%"

        });
</script>
Sample josn data

{
    "items": [
        {

            "PreviewImageUrl": "/images/ui/Default_News.png",
            "Type": "NewsType"
        },
        {
            "PreviewImageUrl": "/images/ui/Default_Blog.png",
            "Type": "BlogType"
        }
    ],
    "total": 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When the `pageSize` is greater than one, the `data` passed to the template is a javascript array, but when it equals one, `data` refers to the JSON object itself. Hence your template needs to be more like this:

```
<script id="scrollview-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
  # if (data != null) { #
    <div data-role="page" style="width:100%;">
      <img class="carousal-image"
        src="#= getPreviewImageUrl(data.Type,data.PreviewImageUrl) #"/>
    </div>
  # } #
</script>
```

Working demo [here](https://dojo.telerik.com/OxEJAWUL). Hope this helps.